# UICollectionViewFlowLayout Subclass transform.m34 causing disappearing cells

Tags: uicollectionview, coverflow, catransform3d, uicollectionviewlayout

I am working on a Coverflow style layout for `UICollectionView`. Its a simple enough concept, and just to make it easier there are about 100 tutorials on the subject. However as anyone doing transforms knows, `m34` is the magic number. However, as soon as I set it to get some perspective for my rotations, the views disappear. The only appear when the rotation is near 0.

I suspect this is a bounds/zIndex issue, however after days of monkeying around with zIndexes and clipping adjustments, the cells just refuse to appear. Any help is **greatly** appreciated.

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSArray *array = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];

    CGRect visibleRect = (CGRect){self.collectionView.contentOffset, self.collectionView.bounds.size};

    CGFloat maxDistance = visibleRect.size.width / 2.0;
    CGFloat maxRotation = M_PI_2;

    [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes * attributes, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        CGFloat distanceFromCenter = CGRectGetMidX(visibleRect) - attributes.center.x;

        CGFloat percentageFromCenter = distanceFromCenter / maxDistance;
        percentageFromCenter = MIN(percentageFromCenter, 1.0);
        percentageFromCenter = MAX(percentageFromCenter, -1.0);

        CGFloat angle = percentageFromCenter * maxRotation;

        CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
//        transform.m34 = 1.0 / -800.0;
        transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, angle, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

        attributes.transform3D = transform;
    }];

    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So thanks to one @mpospese on Twitter. The problem wasn't with the `m34` value itself. It was with a particular feature of `UICollectionView`.

> when frame height exceeds collection view’s height, cells are removed

So in my case I had a `UICollectionViewLayout` specially designed to grab the `height` of the `UICollectionView` and use it for the height of the cells. Problem is, when `m34` is factored in that obviously adjusts the frame and therefore exceeds the bounds. Rather than just clipping the cell like most `UIView` operations would have done pointing directly to the problem, `UICollectionView` actually automatically removes cells entirely if they so much as brush the outer-bounds.